# How to implement child/nested routing in react js function component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-router-dom

I have App.js with following route configuration

```
<Routes>
  {
    navbarRoutes.map((route) => (
      <Route key={route.path} path={route.path} element={route.main}>
    ))
  }
</Routes>
```

and route constant file is as follows

```
const navbarRoutes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    text: ''user,
    exact: true,
    main: <User>
  },
  {
    path: '/useraddress',
    text: ''useraddress,
    exact: true,
    main: <useraddress>
  }
]
```

How can I implement nested route or child route inside "/useraddress" and inside App.js as well?

Comment: I think that your main key cannot be called like this, it should be a React component

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'implement nested route or child route inside "/useraddress" and inside App.js as well'? What are you trying to do? What is the goal to accomplish? What is the issue? Also, it's probably just a typo writing the question, but the `text` properties have invalid values. `useraddress` also isn't a valid React component, it should be Capitalized/PascalCased, i.e `Useraddress`.

Answer (score 0):

So here is your solution :

I think that your problem was to not call the Component like this <route.main />

Basically we have navbarRoutes like this :

```
// I import all the components before 
const navbarRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    element: Welcome
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    element: About
  }
];
```

A path and an element (by the way I think that we don't need the exact property  no more). Then we map it where we have put our BrowserRouter

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    {navbarRoutes.map((T) => (
      <Route key={T.path} path={T.path} element={<T.element />} />
    ))}
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

You can try it out on this [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-bird-n6uwkz?file=/src/App.js:160-349), there is a route /about and another one at the index :)

> PS : the **T** is just a parameter you can call it whatever you want

Answer (score -1):

Use this pattern and also do it manually. Don't use loop

```
<Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/upcomingTournament" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path ="/deposit" element={<Deposit />} />
        <Route path='/withdraw' element={<Withdraw/>} />
        <Route path='/deleteData' element={<DeleteOldData />} />
        <Route path="/createMatch" element={<CreateMatch />} />
        <Route path="/shop" element={<Shop />} />
        <Route path="/roomPass" element={<RoomDetails/>} />
        <Route path="/refund/:id" element={<Refund />} />
        <Route path="/result/:id" element={<Result />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
```